# Powershell replacement behavior

Tags: powershell

I executed the following ps command and it shown a strange result:

`"version: 1.0.0.0, count: 1200000" -replace "1.0.0.0", "1.1.0.0"`

The result is:

```
version: 1.1.0.0, count: 1.1.0.0
```

Why does the string "1200000" get replaced?

PS version:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.16299.98
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.16299.98
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `.` character as it means any character in regex (except line breaks) :

```
"version: 1.0.0.0, count: 1200000" -replace "1\.\0\.0\.0", "1.1.0.0"
```

As `'1.0.0.0'` is exact match of `"1200000"` in regex

> **The dot matches a single character, without caring what that character
>   is**. The only exception are line break characters.

See: https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Another option is using the [Regex.Escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) Method

> Escapes a minimal set of characters (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^,
>   $,., #, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes.

For example:

```
$EscapeString = [regex]::Escape("1.0.0.0")
"version: 1.0.0.0, count: 1200000" -replace $EscapeString, "1.1.0.0"
```

Comment: "As '1.1.0.0' is exact match of "1200000" in regex", shouldn't it be '1.0.0.0' here?